# How to avoid method=POST,uri=http://localhost:8080/example/done, status=400, reason=Bad Request

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I created a rest api and now I am testing on it. I use another java web application to test it on localhost.

Here is my testing,

```
Patient patient=new Patient();
patient.setIdpatient(3);

UnitType unitType=new UnitType();
unitType.setIdunitType(16);

Units units=new Units();
units.setPatient(patient);
units.setUnitType(unitType);
units.setUnitMeasurement("mg");
units.setDateCreated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());
units.setLastUpdated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());            

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();                
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/example/done");    
Response post = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .post(Entity.entity(units, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

out.print(post.toString());
```

I use jersey to build my rest api.

When I run this code in a servlet, following message is displayed on the browser.

```
InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:8080/example/done, status=400, reason=Bad Request}}
```

This is not working for POST and PUT methods in my rest api.

This is my **web.xml** file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Tester</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.Tester</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Tester</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Tester</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

But , when I put this code on a servlet in my rest api project, this is worked without any block.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Unit Testing your rest api ?

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto: Testing my rest api. I used postman and it worked . Now I want to know why this is not working in java ?

Comment: Use postman to test the URL first if it works fine then check arguments that are to be passed from data section (in case of POST request) if it causes the error again check the data type of the arguments, it solves bad request error for me most of the time

Comment: Also make sure that you are creating the correct type of request depending on what task you are performing from within that service

Comment: @Milind : I have done your suggestions . Is there anything else ?

Comment: Try restarting the server several times